# How to generate JSON sample from JSON schema using Python?

Tags: python, json

We are engaged in microservices that exchange JSON messages with each other. Somehow they themselves came to use JSONSchema for generation. The JAVA was used for generation and everything was good if the developer was nearby. But what about the analytics that coordinate the fields with the customer?

He needs an operational tool to generate a message and show it to the customer. Well...the first thing that comes to mind is the good old AltovaXMLSpy. A great remedy, but unfortunately paid. After working for a month, it stops working. The second remedy is conditionally free LiquidStudio2020. Not Altova, of course, but still - generates and visualizes. But.. after 15 days, basic functions, without paying for a license, become unavailable.

And so the idea arose to write a script in Python. Found the JSONSchema library, even...but nowhere is it described how it has a scheme to generate a message. It feels like it's impossible or we're using the wrong library. I'll tell you right away, online generators should not be offered. We have a complex structure of objects in JSONSchema linked through "$ ref." Does anyone have a similar experience in generating JSON messages?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you done any research in to your problem? If so, share it here and say what you don't understand. As it is your question is very broad and will probably be closed unless you can be more specific about what the problem is. E.g. what do you mean by "JSON sample"?

Comment: ok. I was described the question more in detail

Comment: Hey, give Wirespec a shot. It's free and easy to use for generating JSON responses. https://wirespec.dev

Comment: Thanks, but we want the way in Python. And it is a quest why well known library JsonSchema can't create JSON message....